# How the get all items/controls in asp.net form using name attribute in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have got a `div` and `fieldset` both named "seeConsent" in a asp.net form like below:

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post" class="myClass" runat="server" id="myform" style="align-content: center">
        <div class="container" runat="server">
            <div class="row" runat="server">
                ...
                <div class="spec" runat="server">
                   ...
                   <div runat="server">
                       ...
                       <div class="step" runat="server" name="SeeConsent">...</div>
                   </div>
                   ...
                   <fieldset runat="server" name="SeeConsent">...
                   </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
</form>
```

Note that I need to perform a `visible=true/false` process on those fields in the back end. Therefore, I need a loop in the `aspx.cs` file to check each control, detect the ones with "seeConsent" name and set their visibility based on a boolean parameter `seeConsent`, which is received from web.config. If it was a windows form, it would work like that:

```
foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c. Name.Equals("SeeConsent"))
        c.Visible = seeConsent;
}
```

However, since it is a `System.Web.UI.Control` instead, and it does not have a `Name` property. I couldn't find out how to get the values of `name` attributes of the div and fieldsets inside the form on C#. I have tried to check `c.Page.Request.Form.AllKeys`, but the value of it is [string{0}].

Any advice would be so appreciated.

Comment: If you want to process it at serverside, use servercontrols. In this case a `Panel`. Put also a `Panel` around your fieldset.

Comment: So when I put a panel, will I see c.Page.Request.Form.AllKeys is including the panels? @TimSchmelter